# How do I find the last argument being passed INTO a script from $@?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash 

/home/someDir/myServer $@

#arguments go as follow: ./server IP SERVICE PORT

port = $@ ?

echo "your port "$port
```

This IS NOT what I'm looking for: last_arg="${!#}"

Comment: more information please?

Comment: If you know you're supposed to get 3 args, why not `port=$3`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `${@: -1:1}` (the space is mandatory, otherwise it gets confused and thinks you're using defaulting) will do it; the slice syntax, unlike subscripts, allows negative numbers to index from the end of the array.